# Ajax update, comparing and insert data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Good day,
As mention in the topic, I'm creating a ajax function where the php will directly update the status then if the status is 1 (or approve), it will compare between 2 table (tblcompany and tblinternapplication) and doing insert new company if the company not in the list. I tried test one by one it function well but after combine it doesn't add any new company when the person application approved (or set to 1) even the status in tblinternapplication updated. Below is my code.

```
 <?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
 <?php require_once("sessioncourse.php"); ?>
 <?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
 <?php require_once("../includes/connection.php") ?>
 <?php require_once("../includes/functions.php") ?>

 <?php

 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $status =$_GET['status'];

 $sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  =     
 ".mysql_real_escape_string($status) ." WHERE id = " .mysql_real_escape_string($id);
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 $querysel = "SELECT i.company_code, c.company_name as cn, i.company_name as ic, 
               c.company_branch as cb, i.company_branch as ib, FROM tblcompany c, 
               tblinternapplication i WHERE i.id = '$id' ";
 $resultsel = mysql_query($querysel, $connection);
 $queryselc = "SELECT 
    company_name, company_branch,
    company_address, post_code,
    company_city, company_state,
    company_country,
    company_phone, company_fax,
    company_url FROM tblinternapplication WHERE id = '$id' ";
 $resultselc = mysql_query($queryselc, $connection);

 if ($status == 1){
  while($rowsel = mysql_fetch_array($resultsel)){
   if($rowsel['company_code'] == NULL){
    if(($rowsel['cn'] != $rowsel['ic']) OR ($rowsel['ib'] != $rowsel['cb'])){
    while($rowselc = mysql_fetch_array($resultselc)){
      $query = "INSERT INTO tblcompany (
      company_name, company_branch,
      company_address, post_code,
      company_city, company_state, company_country, 
      company_phone, company_fax,
      company_url
  ) VALUES (
  '{$rowselc['company_name']}', '{$rowselc['company_branch']}',
      '{$rowselc['company_address']}','{$rowselc['post_code']}',
      '{$rowselc['company_city']}','{$rowselc['company_state']}',
      '{$rowselc['company_country']}',
      '{$rowselc['company_phone']}','{$rowselc['company_fax']}',
      '{$rowselc['company_url']}'
  )";
  $resultc = mysql_query($query, $connection); 
    }
   }
  }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: So, where is the Ajax code

Comment: ajax code i didn't post because that code doesn't come out any problem.

Comment: You don't need to open and close your php-tags at the beginning of the file. just open them once.

Comment: ok,noted but i put php-tags beginning is to standardize all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share the answer using my own method. Basically I remove 2-level nested while and make the first query row match then the second is to search for result. Hope this will help others.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];

$sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  = 
".mysql_real_escape_string($status) ." WHERE id = " .mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$querysel = "SELECT i.company_code, i.company_name, i.company_branch, c.company_name,   
c.company_branch FROM tblinternapplication i, tblcompany c WHERE i.company_name = 
c.company_name AND i.company_branch = c.company_branch AND i.id = '$id' ";
$resultsel = mysql_query($querysel, $connection);

$queryselc = "SELECT * FROM tblinternapplication where id = '$id'";
$resultselc = mysql_query($queryselc, $connection);

if ($status == 1){
if(mysql_num_rows($resultsel) == 0){
    while($rowselc = mysql_fetch_array($resultselc)){
$query = "INSERT INTO tblcompany (
    company_name, company_branch,
    company_address, post_code,
    company_city, company_state, company_country, 
    company_phone, company_fax,
    company_url
) VALUES (
'{$rowselc['company_name']}', '{$rowselc['company_branch']}',
    '{$rowselc['company_address']}','{$rowselc['post_code']}',
    '{$rowselc['company_city']}','{$rowselc['company_state']}',
    '{$rowselc['company_country']}',
    '{$rowselc['company_phone']}','{$rowselc['company_fax']}',
    '{$rowselc['company_url']}'
)";
$resultc = mysql_query($query, $connection); 
    }
 }
}


?>
```

if anyone have recommendation welcome to leave comments.
Thank you.